# Which to use, QueuedConnection or QMutex to make an object thread-safe?

Tags: c++, multithreading, qt

I'm building an application that needs to load thousands of HTML files, analyze them and then put them into something like HashMap which is global, and I decided to use multi-thread to fasten the speed.

So question occurs that which I should use, QueuedConnection for signal/slots or QMutex to make the HashMap thread-safe.

I was using QueueConnection to make everything simpler, I created a lot of sub-threads to load and signal the pointer back to main thread to analyze them and put them into HashMap, it works fine then.

However, as I read some comments that QueueConnection is actually really time-consuming then I started to re-construct my code and used QMutex to make my HashMap thread-safe, then I can do all the work (load, analyze, put them into HashMap) in the sub-threads.

But the results are not very optimistic, the latter way consumes much more time than the former.

Is QueueConnection really a better way to do the work?

Example codes are as follows:

Using QueuedConnection:

```
class Html
{
    void create();
    {
      /* Load from local file */
    }
    void analyze()
    {
        /* Pick out every word and put them into the inverted list */
        QString word = this->getNextWord();
        /* What's stored in the hashmap is a list */
        List list = HashMap::globalInstance()->getList(word);
        /* Do some work like checking */
        list->append(this);
    }
}



class LoadHtml : public QThread
{
signals:
    void processHtml(Html* ptr);
public:
    void run()
    {
        Html* ptr = new Html();
        ptr->create();
        emit processHtml(ptr);
    }
}

class MainThread: public QThread
{
private:
    LoadHtml loadHtml;
slots:
    void processHtml(Html* ptr)
    {
        ptr->analyze();
    }
    void run()
    {
        connect(&loadHtml,LoadHtml::processHtml,this,MainThrad::processHtml,Qt::QueuedConnection);
        loadHtml.start();
    }
}
```

And the QMutex version is like simply deleting the signals/slots and put QMutex in all of the methods of `HashMap` and `List` and try to do `analyze()` in `LoadHtml`.

Comment: Sound like it in this case.  However, you could be doing too much work after acquiring the mutex (where 'too much' means 'more than absolutely necessary').  Have you tried a concurrent hash map?

Comment: Do you have examples of the two different code attempts?

Comment: @1201ProgramAlarm Sorry that I didn't explain specifically,what's stored in the hashmap is pointer of a list of htmls,what I'm doing is trying to create an inverted list, I think 'too much work' must be in the list rather than the hashmap itself.

Comment: @RobbieE I added the code examples and thanks for your comment.

Comment: I don't think mutex or queued connection synchronisation times are something similar to the time to parse and process html, so I would implement it the easiest way __definitely__

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The mutex will be the faster solution of the two, since in the case of frequent access, the queued connection overhead will be so high that using multiple threads will actually be much slower than using a single thread with direct connections.

But I'd suggest a different solution and a much better one. Instead of storing job results directly in the global hash map, have a local hash map for each job and use that to store the results in as you go, and only after the job is completed, merge the results from the local into the global hash map. This will minimize queued connection or mutex lock/unlock from once for every word to once for every job. This will give you the best performance. This way the difference between using queued connections or mutex will be negligible, so you can simply use the easier and cleaner solution.

However, looking at your code sample, I'd say performance is not your current concern. Is that from your actual code, or just a very, very bad example? It doesn't make sense.